# What techniques exist for energy-efficient computing and networking?

Tags: reference-request, computer-architecture, operating-systems, computer-networks, power-consumption

I am currently reviewing the potentials of cloud computing regarding energy efficiency and green IT. In connection with this review I am having a look on techniques for increasing energy-efficiency in data centers (computing), hardware, networking and storage devices.

Specificially for computing/servers I have found already a few:

- energy-aware scheduling techniques utilizing frequency and voltage scaling
- virtualization to consolidate server resources
- energy-saving hardware, e.g. ACPI, several processor techniques, especially for mobile devices etc.

However, for networking devices it is rather hard to get information about energy-saving technologies. I have read that people are thinking about new protocols and alternative routing methods to be able to switch off hardware if the network is under low load. Does anyone know of such examples?

Which other points should be added, either for networking or computing

Comment: As it is, this question seems very broad. I might refer you to the Supercomputing 2011 proceedings for a great many papers on power efficiency of hardware and data centers. When I have time, I'd be happy to provide a few references. Off hand, what about GPUs and ARM processors, fast non-volatile RAM technologies to reduce static power, and optical interconnect networks (http://iee.ucsb.edu/content/optical-interconnects-and-switching-reduce-power-consumption). Can you narrow the question down at all?

Answer (score 4):

I only know very little about this topic. But from the algorithmic point of view there is a [very nice review article](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2010/5/87271-energy-efficient-algorithms/fulltext) from Susanne Albers, which is probably a good starting point.